# how to set the css for special price products on cms page

Tags: magento-1.7, cms, css

I have a cms page on which i am showing products having special price only issue with products catalog listing this is link
http://www.motifz.com.pk/special-offer/?___store=default
when select view all the catalog products css out of control please guide me how i fix it thanks in advance
EDIT
following is my xml related with promotional

```
<catalogextensions_index_promotional>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="catalogextensions/promotional_list" name="promotional_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                    <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                </block>
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </catalogextensions_index_promotional>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it issue,with page layout.your view all pages layout is 3-columns   and speciall offer page is 2-columns-left.You need change layout of view all pages.

goto your

```
<catalogextensions_index_promotional translate="label">
<reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
</catalogextensions_index_promotional>
```

**Edit:**

```
   <catalogextensions_index_promotional>
    <!-- set template  -->
    <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
<!-- end of set template -->
            <reference name="content">
                <block type="catalogextensions/promotional_list" name="promotional_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                    <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                        <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                    </block>
                    <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
                </block>
            </reference>
        </catalogextensions_index_promotional>
```

See more at http://www.amitbera.com/how-to-change-page-layout-in-magento/

Comment: i have update my question and post my xml related promotional page

Comment: what i add in <!--add here--> please guide me more thanks in advance

Comment: i have set template ... using xml